# .hide() not working correctly on iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad

I have an image slide show based off an array of images that feeds a single img element on my page. When I reach the last image and press "next", which triggers the nextImage() function, I want to hide my final image and bring up a splash screen (a div on the same page, hidden by css). This code works great in safari but it doesn't seem to hide the image element on iPad (my target device). I am at a loss as to what may be causing this to not work.

```
function endPresentation(){
    $("#image").hide(200);
    $("#test").show(200);
}

//Goto Next image in array
function nextImage(){

    save();
    iCount++;

//If there are no more images in the array
    if (images[iCount] == null) {
        endPresentation();
    }
    else{                       
        //Change image source to new image, do stuff after the image has successfully loaded
        $("#image").attr("src", images[iCount]).load(function (){               
            doStuff();  
        });         
    }               
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this has been bugging me for weeks!

Comment: I have determined that the issue is with the timers in .show() and hide().

It appears the iPad doesn't like animation.

I will leave this open as now that I have it working the animation would be nice, and for future reference this is being tested on an iPad3.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved adding a 10 ms timeout when calling the hide and show methods:

```
function endPresentation(){
  setTimeout(function(){
      $("#image").hide(200);
      $("#test").show(200);
  },10)
}
```

tested on iPad 4

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using jquery to hide the element, try adding `style="display:none"` to the `#image` element in your html. This should make it easier for jquery to toggle the visibility of the image.

Comment: Doing that would simply "hide" the #image element without any animation and that's probably not what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What I would try is to simply hide the last displayed image inside your "if" statement using iCount-- to go back to your last existing image and after that I would, if necessary, simply remove the div with .remove(); Hope it works!

So, you check if iCount is null. If it is, iCount--, hide(200) it and if necessary, you remove the #image with .parent('#image') after animation ends. (You may want to double check the syntax).